# Learning ranking model leveraging multiple noisy pairwise constraints

Tags: ranking, pymc, rating

I am trying to come up with a probabilistic model that (1) learns a pairwise ranking function (2) and leverage multiple noisy pairwise constraints.

My problem setup has two parts:

(1) There are $N$ objects: $O_i, i=1,\ldots,N$. Each object $O_i$ has an associated observed real-valued vector $X_i \in \cal R^d$. The primary goal is to learn a function such that $f(x_i) > f(x_j)$ if the object $O_i$ ranks higher than $O_j$. A regression seems to be a good fit.

(2) There are $K$ processes, $k=1,\ldots,K$. The $k$th process generates a noisy matrix $Z^k_{ij} \in \{0,1\}$, where $i,j=1,\ldots,N$. All matrices have the same size and are fully populated. The value $Z^k_{ij}=1$ if the process prefers object $O_i$ over object $O_j$. The secondary goal is to infer a matrix $Z^*_{ij}$ with latent variables. It is safe to assume that every two processes are independent when generating data.

It makes sense to attribute $k$th process a hidden variable $0<r_k<1$ that denotes the probability of flipping the true pairwise variable $Z^k_{ij}$. In other words, a process of quality will have a small, close to 0 value of $r_k$.

It is not too difficult to implement part (1) separately. The challenge is to build a single model that leverages both sources of information: (1) object features and (2) multiple pairwise constraints as generated by independent processes (experts). In other words, the processes can be considered as experts.

I am struggling creating a single probabilistic model that puts all pieces in one story. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do the object ranks relate to the matrices? Are all the noise-free matrices consistent with a unique rank ordering?

Comment: @GeoMatt22 Object ranks are hidden. The matrices are generated by independent processes that make their judgement on ranking. The object features are merely guesses on what the processes operate to do the ranking.

Comment: @GeoMatt22 Every matrix has definitely a signal in them. The most straightforward approach would be to do majority vote to approximate the noise-free pairwise ranking.

Comment: In general it seems like each matrix corresponds to a directed graph. In principle you would hope that each noise-free matrix would correspond to a digraph which can be at least [topologically ordered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting). So for example a matrix realization with lots of cycles would perhaps be less reliable?

Comment: @GeoMatt22 Actually there is one noise-free matrix that needs to be inferred from object features and $K$ noisy matrices from $K$ experts.

Comment: So is problem 2 not solvable on its own? i.e. could you estimate the matrix from its noisy samples alone? I do not know if majority vote is necessarily the best approach. Another could be to sum up the matrices, to retain some information on relative certainty. As noted before, you may need to do something like [condensation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component#Definitions) to ensure a DAG. Even then the toposort will not be unique. Problem 1 seems to want a total ordering? The weights could be used here, e.g. to select the max-weight topological order?